How to cite in Japanese?
Can I get some help on the correct way to cite a work in Japanese? I am looking for the snippets:
page
pages
p.
pp.
cited on page 15
cited on pages 15, 17, 19
cit. on p. 15
cit. on pp. 15, 17, 19

and so far I have come up with these literal translations, that I am not sure are current usage in bibliography citation.
ページ
ページ
p.
pp.
15 ページに引用
15、17、19 ページに引用
15 ページに引用
15、17、19 ページに引用

Would someone, confirm this, correct it, or point me to the right direction or some work where I can see any material on this or examples?

See also https://chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/58840/how-to-cite-in-chinese

@YusukeMatsubara I am not sure what the Chinese translation might have anything to do with the question above, except that Japanese has used the character (頁) for some time. Maybe you care to elabirate.

First, Japanese do not use abbreviations for "page(s)". The language uses abbreviations for long double-words mostly (like remote-control, University of Tokyo, ...). It is really a contraction not an abbreviation and not for short words. In general, the full word designator is one-character long. So to start with forget about "p." or "pp.".
Next, you can use either 頁 or ページ for page/pages. And that may be what @YusukeMatsubara is referring to above -- the first character is borrowed from Chinese. But you should forget about it anyways and use ページ, because that is mostly what you see theses days.
The rest is correct, but there is one quirk. Unlike western-like citations, Japanese has a designator for "year" which is 年, and that frequently comes with the year, in a citation, if the year does not show up in between parenthesis. There is also a designator for "month" and in case you need that you should use 月.
So for a textbook citation you would have:

生西明夫・中神祥臣：作用素環入門、岩波書店、2007 年 3 月、 xiv+270 ページ (15、17、19ページに引用)。

In the example above it may look like there is a space after the comma (tōten), but there isn't.

Very nice! Can I ask a couple of follow up questions? What is the difference in the use of 頁 and ページ? When does one use western style commas and when to use tōten, in the context of a citation?

@PauloNey I am not really sure, but probably there is some historical reason for both. I know for sure that puctuation has been imported from Chinese around the Meiji era, so very recent. You should ask two separate questions for that -- it will give the opportunity for the people that have been voting this question down, to vote even further. I am not sure what is up with them, but the moderators are certainly sleeping because this is a perfect good question for the forum and has never been asked before.
